# Does Google Play Location Api support other satellites navigation systems than GPS?

Tags: android, location, google-play-services

I'm using the Google Play services location APIs for getting the current user location. But I am unable to find any information on what it does when the device has more capabilities than only gps, i.e. glonass, beidou or even galileo if it goes life within our lifetime.

Does it combine the data from those sources?

Comment: I think the google play location api mostly obtain the data from GPS, and also get the data from the `network provider`. The examples you provided kind of subset of GPS that provided with other countries. I think it will be used accordingly.

Comment: I'd expect some clever combination of those systems too, but I am unable to find anything on it. And if a customer wants to know how our application works, it would be better to be able to point to some documentation.